# The character $\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Consider $\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ to be the least size of a neighbourhood basis of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (note that $w(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}) = w(\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty S^1) = \chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ is the weight of wedge of a countable amount of circles).

According to the paper [The character of $\omega_1$ in first countable spaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041965), $\omega < \chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})\leq \mathfrak{d}$ where $\mathfrak{d}$ is the least cardinality of a dominating subset of $\omega^\omega$. In particular its consistent that $\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})<\mathfrak{c}$.

Does $\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}) = \mathfrak{d}$?

Comment: This paper is also available without registration to Jstor: see [here](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/16773/FleissnerW_PAMS_63(1)149.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Note that $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$ is not quite a wedge a countably many circles.  But the closely related space $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ would be, with the same results.  Recorded in https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000139.

Comment: @PatrickR I know they're not homeomorphic, but writing $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ would led people to believe I'm talking about $S^1$. The weight is the same in any case.

Comment: Yeah, could be confusing, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Remark***
$\mathfrak d$ *and* $d$ *are the same, see the update below.
Hence, the first two paragraphs are obsolete.
(But might still be interesting.)*

Let's start with a note about the dominating number:
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) or also the article of E.K. van Douwen in the Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology, the dominating number $\mathfrak{d}$ is the least cardinal of a set $G$ of functions
from $\omega \rightarrow \omega$ such that for each function
$f: \omega \rightarrow \omega$ there is a $g \in G$ such that
$f \le^* g$, which means $f(n) \le g(n)$
*for all but finitely many* $n$.

According to [The character of $\omega_1$ in first countable spaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041965)
let's define
$d = $  the least cardinal of a set $G$ of functions
from $\omega \rightarrow \omega$ such that for each function
$f: \omega \rightarrow \omega$ there is a $g \in G$ such that
$f \le g$, which means $f(n) \le g(n)$ *for all* $n$.

Of course, $\mathfrak{d} \le d$, but also
$d \le \mathfrak{d} $, see below.

Note that in this paper, it is stated that
$\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}) \le d$ (Example 5).

**To answer the question, we also have
$d \le \chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$:**

Of course, it does not make any difference to consider functions
$\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \ldots \}$ instead of $\omega \rightarrow \omega$.

Let $\mathfrak U$ be a neighborhood base of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ of size $\chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$.
For each $U \in \mathfrak U$ there is function
$f_U: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
$(n- \frac{1}{2 f_U(n)}, \space n + \frac{1}{2 f_U(n)}) \subset U $
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
(To avoid (AC) here, you can define the smallest such function.)

$G := \{f_U: U \in \mathfrak{U}\}$.

Now let $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.
Define $V = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 
 (n- \frac{1}{2f(n)}, \space n + \frac{1}{2 f(n)})$,
which is an open neighborhood of $\mathbb N$.
Hence there is a $U \in \mathfrak{U}$ such that $U \subset V$, which implies $f \le f_U$.

Hence $d \le |G| \le |\mathfrak{U}| = \chi(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$.

**Update**  
In fact, it is $d = \mathfrak{d}$:

Let $G$ be a cofinal subset of $ \space ^\omega\omega$
with respect to $\le^*$ of size $\mathfrak d$.
For $g \in G, A$ a finite subset of $\omega$ and $m \in \omega$ define

$g_{(A,m)}(n) = 
\begin{cases}
g(n),  & \text{if} & n \notin A \\
m, & \text{if} & n \in A
\end{cases}
$

Then $G^\prime = \{g_{(A,m)}: g \in G, 
  A \text{ is a finite subset of } \omega, m \in \omega\}$
has same size as $G$ and is cofinal in
$ \space ^\omega\omega$  with respect to $\le$.

I just noticed that $d = \mathfrak{d}$ is Theorem 3.6. in
E.K. van Douwen, The integers and topology in
Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology.

(*I was just confused, why the dominating number is usually defined in this rather complicated way.*)